# Why messages from Socket.IO server are recieved from time to time?

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io, socketio4net

I have `socket.io` server in `node.js`. All connections come through NGINX. The client is written in C# with `Quobject/SocketIoClientDotNet` library.

The problem is that client receives messages from server only from time to time. 
I have logs in node.js code, so the server tries to send messages. Moreover, there are multiple processes with `TIME_WAIT` state in server (I gat that by netstat) and the number of that processes is equal to number of unsuccessful send attempts by socket.io server.

Otherwise, server always receive messages from clients.
I made nginx settings ("upgrade" headers, etc.) but it didn't help.
I turned off Windows Firewall but it didn't help. 
So, I don't know why such situation happens, I don't know where else to look at and I will appreciate any help from community.